# JMeter: Extracting response from HTTP Request and storing it in a variable

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm using Jmeter to run a stress test for testing out my servers. I'm making several HTTP calls and in response, I get the HTTP response as a numeric string as "500". I want to extract that value from the response and store it in a variable. Also, I want to use that value in "If controller".

Help is appreciated.

Thanks, 
Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number can be saved into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) as follows:

1. Add [Regular Expressions Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above numeric value:
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]

   it will create `${value}` JMeter Variable with the value of `500`

   [image]
3. If you want to use it in the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) you can compare the `${value}` JMeter Variable with `500` using i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) like:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${value} == 500,)}
   ```

   [image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It worked and you made it very easy to understand and was very insightful.